# Weighted nonnegative least squares in R

Tags: r, least-squares

I would like to perform weighted nonnegative least squares in R (i.e. with the constraint that all fitted coefficients are >=0). The `nnls` function in the `nnls` package appears not to support weights. Am I correct that I can simulate `weights` though within the `nnls` function by multiplying both the covariate matrix `X` and the dependent variable `y` by the square root of the `weights` vector, as seems to be indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36112290/weighted-non-negative-least-square-linear-regression-in-python)? Or is there better approaches to do this?

Comment: Hope this links helps: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/srvyr/vignettes/srvyr-vs-survey.html

`srvy` **package allows you to create a matrix with the weights that you indicate**. I work with survey data and cross with the same issue. With this package you can create a matrix with the weights already applied and use it with any other package in such a way that you do not need the package itself include a specific argument to weight the data

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/246913/the-theory-behind-the-weights-argument-in-r-when-using-lm

Comment: I'm familiar with regular weighted least squares, that's not the problem - I'm looking for a function though that allows me to constrain all coefficients to be positive...

Comment: I think you can use the glmnet package: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35927521/r-glmnet-forcing-the-coefficient-to-a-certain-sign

Comment: Yes I know glmnet, and that allows weights and constraints, and with lambda set to zero it does not do any regularization. It is way slower than nnls though, hence my question of whether multiplying X and y by sqrt(weights) within nnls is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1) nnls** Yes, it is equivalent since weighted least squares minimizes:

```
sum( w * (Y - X %*% beta)^2 )
= sum_i( (sqrt(w[i]) * X[i, ] %*% beta - sqrt(w[i]) * Y[i])^2 )
```

subject to constraints where sum_i means sum over i.  Thus `sqrt(w[i])` multiplies the ith row of X and the ith element of Y which is equivalent to using   `sqrt(w) * X` and `sqrt(w) * Y`.  (Note that these are also equal to `diag(sqrt(w)) %*% X` and `c(diag(sqrt(w)) %*% Y)` respectively.)

**2) CVXR**  The CVXR package can do weighted non-negative least squares directly.  There is an example of performing non-negative least squares in its vignette.

```
vignette("cvxr_intro")
```

Just change the objective in the code there to add weights:

```
objective <- Minimize(sum((w *(Y - X %*% betaHat)^2)))
```

**3) nls** `nls` which comes with R can do non-negative weighted least squares if you use the `port` algorithm with lower bounds of all 0. (In the code below we have started at zero and normally it is not a good idea to start on the boundary but given the linearity here it really doesn't matter.)

```
zeros <- numeric(ncol(X))
nls(Y ~ X %*% b, start = list(b = zeros), weights = w, lower = zeros, alg = "port")
```

Run all three approaches to double check the answers.

Comment: For my problem size weighted nnls took 0.25s, glmnet with lambda=0 and lower.limits=0 took 2s (8x slower) and CVXR took 95s (380x slower). A shame that CVX is so slow since I like it's flexibility - hopefully they may incorporate a faster solver like CPLEX in the future... Didn't try nls since I know it's not so robust...

Comment: I suggest you try nls as well.  This comment about it is really not accurate, particularly for a problem like this that is linear.

Comment: Just tried it and nls gives me the error "'Convergence failure: singular convergence (7)'' - so unfortunately this confirmed my suspicion it tends not to be very robust...

Comment: I wouldn't conclude that. If your X matrix is singular that could happen but that just means you have provided an ambiguous specification.

Comment: Well I know for sure my X matrix is not exactly singular though - even if there is quite big collinearity...