# How to implement iteratively reweighted least squares with parameters constrained to be non-negative in R

Tags: r, least-squares, weighted

I am attempting to re-create results found in the 1990 paper "Statistical Modelling of the AIDS Epidemic for Forecasting Health Care Needs" by Brookmeyer and Liao. They use iteratively reweighted least squares, but mentioned that constrained optimization techniques need to be employed. Is there an R package that can do this?

I have tried using methods suggested in the following linked post but have been unable to update them for the iteratively reweighting scheme: [Weighted nonnegative least squares in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47888996/weighted-nonnegative-least-squares-in-r)

Comment: Could you use `mgcv::pcls` in conjunction with the basic IRLS routine implemented at https://bbolker.github.io/stat4c03/notes/glm_comp.pdf ?

Comment: (i.e. substitute `mgcv::pcls` (with appropriate arguments) for `lm.wfit`)

Answer (score 0):

For optimization problems in `R` in general, I would advise to consult the [optimization task view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html).

Now for the specific problem of constrained optimization, you can check if `constrOptim` already fulfills what you need. The allow linear constraints of `constrOptim` should be enough to encode your nonnegativity cosntraints.